# Images not getting scaled up ( Android)

Tags: android, xml

I am using some .png images for my Android app's UI. I have kept the images in the 'res/drawable' directory. I read in some tutorials that Android automatically scales up the images when the screen resolution is bigger than mdpi. But when I run my app on big screened devices, the images are displayed as their original sizes, and not scaled up. Rest of the space is empty( black). What am I doing wrong here? Below is the XML for my layout, if it helps:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" 
      >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:contentDescription="@string/p"

        android:src="@drawable/volbar" />



    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:contentDescription="@string/p"

        android:src="@drawable/head" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="33dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="19dp"
        android:text="@string/press_to_update" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView9"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView2"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:contentDescription="@string/p"

        android:src="@drawable/frag11"
         />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView9"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:contentDescription="@string/p"

        android:src="@drawable/base" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Have you uploaded images to your res folder according to their resolution?

Comment: yes, correct resolutions have been uploaded in drawable-mdpi and hdpi directories.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that you want your image to scale up to fill the space. If that is the case, you will need to specify `scaledType` for your `ImageView`:

```
<ImageView
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:scaleType="cropInside" />
```

Experiment with different values from [ImageView.ScaleType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html) to get the effect you want.

FYI, when you put an image in `res/drawable`, it is scaled according to device density. For instance, if your png is 200x150, it will be scaled to 300x225 on a device with 1.5 density. This scaling happens independent of the `scaleType`.

Comment: ok i'll test that. btw bt scaling i meANT INCREASING SIZE TO FILL SCREEN WHEN THE SCREEN IS BIGGER, AND DECREASING TO FILL SCREEN WHEN SCREEN IS SMALLER. sorry for the caps.